# Аббревиатура для многословного названия

Tags: аббревиатуры

Нужна помощь с аббревиатурой наименования службы:
«Служба контрольно-измерительных приборов, телемеханики и метрологии».
Столкнулся с двояким написанием:
«СКИПиА, ТМ И М» — такое считаю правильным,
«СКИПиА, т/м и м» — такое мне навязывают.
Прошу помочь с конкретными ссылками на актуальные правила русского языка.

Comment: Shampar, почему д. б. большая буква после двоеточия в начале названия?

Answer (score 2):

http://orthographia.ru/orfografia.php?sid=94 (по Справочнику Лопатина)

В вашем варианте аббревиатуры союз "и" должен передаваться строчной буквой (Лопатин, § 208, примечание 2), например: "**СКИПиА**" (А - "автоматики"?), "**ТМиМ**" (или напр. **СКИПТМиМ**, с прочтением "скиптээм-и-эм" - если это название одной службы). Ср.: **ЦПКиО** (цепэкэО, "и" не читается) - Центральный парк культуры и отдыха. На практике часто и вовсе "и" опускают (ИТМО - Институт точной механики **и** оптики). То, что вам предлагают, не является инициальной аббревиатурой, по форме это внутритекстовые (обычно самоочевидные) *графические сокращения* (Лопатин, § 208, примечание 3), не очень подходящие для сокращения названия ("т/м" ближе к сокращению "ж/д" и даже напоминает ценник в рыбном магазине: б/г = "без головы"; одиночная же буква "м" при таких сокращениях требует точки).